# How to get TargetPath programmatically + GacUtil registering

Tags: c#, biztalk, gac, gacutil

What do i need? I wrote some BizTalk Functoid and BizTalk Pipeline Components. But before you can use them in a mapping (Functoid) or in a pipeline (Pipeline Components) you need to copy it to a specific folder.

Copy it to the folder is not a problem. The problem i have is to get the target path.
I wrote an addin. So you can click on a menu item. You also selected the project of the functoid. So when you now click on the menu item. It should get the targetPath of that assembly. It needs to copy the "dll" file to my other folder.

How can i get that "TargetFolder" programmatically?

Also how can i register the assembly to the GAC? In a batfile i use

"gacutil /i 'path of assembly' /f"

With the /f parameter we force to overwrite the assembly. In c# you can't force that. Do you need then first try to remove the assembly and register it to the GAC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by first check if the assembly exists in the GAC. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Copying the Appropriate Gacutil.exe and Gacutil.exe.config from the following C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin
and place them in your .bat folder.

and programmatically:

refer this :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/helloworld/archive/2008/09/22/how-to-install-assemblies-to-the-gac-programmatically.aspx

Hope this Helps

Thanks,
Nihar Malali

Comment: That's not the thing i need. There is a function in c# Publish. But you don't have a parameter to force overwriting the dll. So my question was, do you need first then delete the dll? What if the dll not exists?

Answer (score 0):

### Custom Pipeline Components

Custom BizTalk Pipeline Components need to be deployed to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\Pipeline Components\ directory for them to be available in Visual Studio from the Pipeline Toolbox.

However, to get a Custom Pipeline Component into the Toolbox you have to jump through a couple of additional hoops. You need to right-click anywhere on the Toolbox and select 'Choose Items' - this will load the 'Choose Toolbox Items'. Navigate to 'BizTalk Pipeline Components' and so long as you have implemented the necessary component interfaces, you should see your custom component listed here (see screenshot below). Tick the checkbox corresponding to your component and select 'Ok'. Your custom component will now be displayed in the Toolbox. If you drag the component onto your Receive or Send Pipeline in Visual Studio, a reference to your Assembly will be created in the relevant project.

[image: Add BizTalk Custom Pipeline Components and Mapper Functoids Dialog]

You will need to GAC the Custom Pipeline Component Assembly, however that is simply a matter of drag and drop into the GAC through Windows Explorer. You might also want to check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578035.aspx which has some good detail on BizTalk deployment options, including GAC-ing assemblies.

### Custom Mapper Funtoids

Custom Functoids are used in a similar way - follow the instructions above for adding a component to the Toolbox, but select select 'BizTalk Mapper Funtoids' instead. You will also need to GAC the assembly.

Comment: Hi Nick, i know that you need to copy that to that folder, but that was not the question. I use now a bat file with an argument ("targetPath") to copy that from the targetPath to that folder. I am writing a VS addin now. But i need the targetPath from the selected project so i know what dll i need to copy to the right folder

Comment: I'm not entirely clear why you need to get the Target Path or write an Add-in. Could you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: We now writing some pipeline components/functoids in VS. We added a bat file to the external tools menu. In that bat file we copy the components/functoids to folder where you need it to work with VS. We get the targetPath now as an argument so we now, which dll we need to copy to the destination folder. But now we need to copy on each dev system the bat files and we also need to add it to the external tools. I am writing now some addin that can copy the dll to the folder an register it in the GAC. But then i need the targetPath, so i know what dll i need to copy to the destination folder